# strotime with a difference of 20 months

Tags: php, strtotime

I try to create a new date with **strotime** with a difference of 20 months, but if i put "+20 months" or "+1 year 10 months" as first argument it doesn't work.

But if i put "+2 years" it work, so i guess i m not so far but even after reading documentation on php.net i m not able to make it work.

My code:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$expire = $res['expire'];
//$newdate = strtotime ( '+20 months' , strtotime ( $expire ) ) ; //NOT OK
$newdate = strtotime ( '+2 years' , strtotime ( $expire ) ) ; //OK
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: does `$today` and `$expire` share the same value? works fine here

Comment: what is the value in $res['expire'] ?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?! What result do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: u mean without spaces ? anyway it s nor working

Comment: the value of $expire is "2012-06-19"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$expire = "2014-6-19";
$newDate=strtotime ( '+20 months' , strtotime ( $expire ));
echo date("Y-m-d",$newDate);    //2016-02-19
```

That seems to work perfectly fine. That's the date after 20 months. What's the format of your date contained in `$expire`?

Comment: I dont understand but i took your code to replace mine and now with "+1 year 10 months" it s workin as expected. thanks a lot Hanky